Apexcharts in react-bootstrap isn't graphing even though console.log shows useState is able to grab it from flask
The goal: get json dumps of arrays from flask and graph them with apexcharts
So to start. There 6 element list named arr in flask that returns it as a json: return  json.dumps(arr)
Then in react-bootstrap I use fetch to retrieve the array useEffect to put it in a variable,
chartData. Console log shows the variables in localhost. I tested displaying the variables too, they display fine on the localhost page. However, the problem I have arises when using Apex-Charts.
Using the basic apexchart found here https://apexcharts.com/docs/react-charts/ gives
import React, {useState, useEffect,Container} from 'react'
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";

function App() {
  const [chartData, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/halp")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then( chartData => {        
        setData({
          chartData,
          options: {
            chart: {
              id: "basic-bar"
            },
            xaxis: {
              categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
            }
          },
          series: [
            {
              name: "series-1",
              data: chartData
            }
          ]
        })
        console.log(chartData)
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <container> 
      <div className="app">
        <div className="row">
          {(typeof chartData.members === 'undefined')
            ? (<p>Loading</p>)
            :(
              <Chart
                options={chartData.options}
                series={chartData.series}
                type="bar"
                width="500"
              />
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </container>
  );
}

export default App;


at line 21. This is where I think the problem is. The format of arr when it is passed in is [0,1,2,3,4,5], and console.log shows the same.
I've tried doing data: chartData using this link in iterating with react https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html data: chartData(i => i) however when I do this chartData "becomes not a function" when I do optional chaining later.
Also for the chart portion I have looked through the list that pops up before posting and saw something about a timer. It doesn't help.
Adding it"
<Chart
  options={chartData.options}
  series={chartData.series}
  type="bar"
  width="500"
/>


I'm not entirely sure why you're putting options like that in the chartData useState, as chartData only contains [0,1,2,3,4,5] according to your post. Instead, directly populate chartData with the data from your endpoint. In the example below I've used your preferred data to populate the chartData.
Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fgw3qr
Options and series
Create a separate options and series constant, as shown in the example.
Fetching the data
You might want to tweak the fetch method depending on the datastructure you're receiving.The takeaway here is that your series data is stored in the chartData variable.
Final thoughts
You might want to check the Container component you're importing from React. React doesn't have a Container component as far as I'm aware. Also, in your code you're invoking a lowercase <container/>.
If you have any questions, feel free to ask.
import React, { useState, useEffect, Container } from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";

function App() {
  //For example purposes the array is populated. Empty the array to have it filled by the endpoint
  const [chartData, setData] = useState([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

  //your fetch method to populate chartData
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/halp")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      });
  });
  const options = {
    chart: {
      id: "basic-bar",
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999],
    },
  };

  const series = [
    {
      name: "series-1",
      data: chartData,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <container>
      <div className="app">
        <div className="row">
          {!chartData?.length ? (
            <p>Loading</p>
          ) : (
            <Chart options={options} series={series} type="bar" width="500" />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </container>
  );
}

export default App;

